# Why did Everworld end so abruptly?

Tags: k-a-applegate, everworld-series

Everworld is a series of 12 books published by K. A. Applegate from 1999 to 2001. In the last book, *Entertain the End*, the main characters help a major god be freed, but the war isn't over.  Yes, the kids have elected to stay in Everworld, but the main struggle in Everworld still exists.

With so many story lines left open, why was the decision made to end Everworld so abruptly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

KA Applegate did a Reddit IAMA session in 2001. The implication seems to be that her decision to stop writing the Everworld novels was driven by dramatically declining sales figures compared to the large commitment required to generate new novels.

> **Q.** *The Everworld series was probably my favorite thing to read as a teenager. It seems like it would be the perfect material for a movie
> and or series. Has there been any interest shown in that regard?*
>
> **katherineapplegate:** *Thanks. You and six other people. No Hollywood love yet. It's all complicated and controlled by
> Scholastic.*
>
> **Q.** ***Was the series not popular?** I figured the blend of mythology, magic and aliens would appeal to a large audience.*
>
> **katherineapplegate:** *No, it died a painful (and not very slow) death.*
>
> <sub><sup>[IAm K.A. Applegate, author of Animorphs and many other books. AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/gzhau/iam_ka_applegate_author_of_animorphs_and_many/)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>Note that I've edited slightly to remove chatter.</sup></sub>

---

As regards the final book (terminating the series) it would appear that the author wasn't especially pleased with it either.

> **Q.** *Are you satisfied with how EverWorld ended? It wasn't very satisfactory as a reader. Can you explain why you ended it the way you
> did?*
>
> **katherineapplegate:** *I'm not happy with the EW ending. Basically I overcommitted. We could keep up with 140 pages a month -- barely --
> but Everworld was 250. We got in over our heads.*

---

Additionally, there seems to have been a certain amount of burnout on the part of the author

> **katherineapplegate:** *In an exhausted, burned out wheeze. By the 4th Remnants and the next
> to last Everworld, we were burned out. Really done for. 150 books
> between 1989 and whatever it was, 2000. It was nuts and we had to
> stop. We didn't write at all for about 5 years.*